# Extremely high usage of memory in grid view

Tags: android, performance, gridview

I tried to make a simple GridView with resized images and as a result i get a extremely high usage of devices memory (43.57 MB) what I do wrong here?

My GridView fragment:

```
public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment {
    private ArrayList<String> mPathList;
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private GalleryAdapter mAdapter;
    private GridView mGridView;

private static final  String TAG = "GalleryFragment";

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_layout, container, false);

    new AsyncGalleryLoader().doInBackground();

    mGridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridView);

    mAdapter = new GalleryAdapter(mPathList);

    mGridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    return view;
}

private class GalleryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

    public GalleryAdapter(ArrayList<String> items) {
        super(getActivity(), 0, items);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null){
            convertView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.gallary_item, parent, false);
        }

        if (mPathList.size() > 0){
            String path = mPathList.get(position);
            mImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.gallary_item_imageView);

            BitmapDrawable bitmap = PictureUtils.getScaledDrawable(getActivity(), path);
            mImageView.setImageDrawable(bitmap);
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}

private class AsyncGalleryLoader extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<String>> {

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        List<PhotoData> datas = PhotoData.listAll(PhotoData.class);
        mPathList = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 1; i<datas.size(); i++){
            try{
                String path = datas.get(i).getPath();
                File file = new File(path);
                if (file.exists()){
                    mPathList.add(path);
                }else {
                    datas.get(i).delete();
                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                Log.d(TAG, "Error");
            }
        }
        return mPathList;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> strings) {
        super.onPostExecute(strings);
    }
}
```

}

And a class that I use to resize image from the device:

```
public class PictureUtils {

    public static BitmapDrawable getScaledDrawable(Activity activity, String path){
        Display display = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        float bestWidth = display.getWidth();
        float bestHeight = display.getHeight();

        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);

        float srcWidth = options.outWidth;
        float srcHeight = options.outHeight;

        int inSampleSize = 1;
        if(srcHeight > bestHeight || srcWidth > bestWidth){
            if(srcWidth > srcHeight){
                inSampleSize = Math.round(srcHeight / bestHeight);
            }else {
                inSampleSize = Math.round(srcWidth / bestWidth);
            }
        }
        options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = inSampleSize;

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
        return new BitmapDrawable(activity.getResources(), bitmap);
    }

    public static void cleanImageView(ImageView view){
        if (!(view.getDrawable() instanceof BitmapDrawable))
            return;
        BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable) view.getDrawable();
        drawable.getBitmap().recycle();
        view.setImageDrawable(null);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why you don't use RecycleView? or at least ViewHolder? the call to             mImageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.gallary_item_imageView);
 is very unefficient

Comment: i used a ViewHolder pattern and i get the same result =(

Comment: I don't say it is the problem. I just mention that your code is unefficient

Comment: thanks for the tip anyway, ill try to make this in RecyclerView when the main problem will be dealt with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `getScaledDrawable()` method fetch bitmap and scale it to the size of device screen. As I understand what you really need is to fetch only thumbnail which should be of the size of single item in grid view. So just rewrite it to take size of your grid item `public static BitmapDrawable getScaledDrawable(Activity activity, String path, int bestWidth, int bestHeight)`.